# Integration variables in path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

The path integral kernel for a one-dimensional system is given by
$$K(x_a,x_b,t_a,t_b) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi \hbar i \epsilon}}^N
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\exp \left( \frac{i}{\hbar} S[x] \right) dx_1 \ldots dx_{N-1}$$
where
$$S[x] = \int_{t_a}^{t_b} L(x,\dot{x}) dt$$
See formulas (2.27) and (2.26) in [the PhD thesis of I. Ruokosenmäki](http://iki.fi/trantala/paths/Ruokosenmaki-PhDThesis.w(19).pdf).
How does the action $S[x]$ depend on the integration variables $x_i$?

Comment: See eq. (2.25).

Comment: But if if we use eq.(2.25) shouldn't we use $S_N$ instead of $S[x]$ in integral (2.27)?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.